# Alias not registered

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, xstream

I'm using XStream in my SpringBoot project, and I define the `Marshaller` bean in my `Configuration` as follows:

```
@Autowired
XStreamMarshaller marshaller;

@Bean
public XStreamMarshaller getXStreamMarshaller() {
    XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
    xstreamMarshaller.setSupportedClasses(Report.class);
    xstreamMarshaller.getXStream().alias("directory", Directory.class);
    return xstreamMarshaller;
}
```

However, the type alias for `directory` is not registered; that is, unmarshalling

```
<directory></directory>
```

throws

> Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: directory

Whereas if I declare the alias on the marshaller explicitly, it works OK:

```
@PostConstruct
void foo() throws XmlMappingException, IOException {
    InputStream is = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("directory.xml");
    this.marshaller.getXStream().alias("directory", Directory.class);
    Directory d = (Directory) this.marshaller.unmarshal(new StreamSource(is));
}
```

In addition, my `Directory` type already has the annotation `@XstreamAlias`, so I don't understand why I need to add this alias at all.

```
@XStreamAlias("directory")
public class Directory {

}
```

So my questions are:

1. Why doesn't adding the `alias` work in the `@Bean` definition?
2. Can I configure not not need *both* the `alias()` call *and* the `@XstreamAlias` annotation?

Comment: is Directory a inner class?

Comment: @Tiina no it's not

Comment: Based on the offered information, I guess there might be class loader conflict, the one for marshaling and the one for Directory class are different.